# NSThread Error in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsthread

I am getting this error

bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x1b53d0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

what is this due to ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the limited information you gave, I assume that you create a UIView (or any of it'subclass) from a thread.

Try using the following instead:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:<#(SEL)aSelector#>
                       withObject:<#(id)arg#> 
                    waitUntilDone:<#(BOOL)wait#>];
```

== edit ==

If that's your appDelegate which gets the callback from the thread, try adding a new method besides your callback:

```
- (void) setMyImage:(UIImage*)theImage { 
   ... 
   myUIImageView.image = theImage; 
   ...
}
```

and call this from 
the thread as mentioned above:

```
- (void) callBackWithImage:(UIImage*)imageFromUrl { 
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setMyImage:) 
                           withObject:imageFromUrl 
                        waitUntilDone:NO]; 
}
```

Comment: In my viewDidLoad method, i am creating a UIImageView. Then I am calling a thread , which gets the image from an URL , and inside the thread method I am setting the image for that ImageView.